# PIvoting table around date column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pivot this table

```
timetableId, assignmentId, dateChecked, hoursWorked
          1,       11,      2017-09-10,     5
          2,       12,      2017-09-10,     5
          3,       13,      2017-09-11,     8
          4,       11,      2017-09-11,     8
          5,       12,      2017-09-11,     8
          6,       13,      2017-09-10,     8
```

so that it would show

```
assignmentId, tenth,  eleventh
          11,      5,   8
          12,      5,   8
          13,      0,   8
```

I have the following code based on the tutorial from this website http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

```
create view timetable_extended as (
 select
    timetables.assignmentId,
    case when dateChecked = '10-09-2017' then timetables.hoursWorked end as tenth,
    case when dateChecked = '11-09-2017' then timetables.hoursWorked end as eleventh
   from timetables
);

create view timetable_extended_Pivot as (
 select
   assignmentId,
   sum(tenth) as tenth,
   sum(eleventh) as eleventh
 from timetable_extended
 group by assignmentId
);

create view timetable_extended_Pivot_Pretty as (
  select 
  assignmentId, 
  coalesce(tenth, 0) as tenth, 
  coalesce(eleventh, 0) as eleventh
 from timetable_extended_Pivot
);
```

however for some reason the first view returns all values as null instead of doing what it is supposed to do - namely this

```
    assignmentId, tenth,  eleventh
          11,      5,       NULL
          11,      NULL     8
          12,      5,       NULL
          12,      NULL     8
          13,      NULL,    8
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to convert the date to a string?

I have tried the same code with string as the main column and it works perfectly

```
create table User_Items
(
 Cust_Names varchar(10),
 Item_Type  varchar(50),
 Item_Amount float
 );

insert into User_Items values
 ('Alison', 'Computer', 345.39),
 ('Alison', 'Monitor', 123.45),
 ('Jason', 'Computer', 435.34),
 ('Jason', 'Monitor', 158.23),
 ('Jason', 'Software', 243.54);

 create view User_Items_Extended as (
  select
   User_Items.Cust_Names,
   case when Item_Type = "Computer" then Item_Amount end as Computer,
   case when Item_Type = "Monitor" then Item_Amount end as Monitor,
   case when Item_Type = "Software" then Item_Amount end as Software
  from User_Items
 );

create view User_Items_Extended_Pivot as (
 select
  Cust_Names,
  sum(Computer) as Computer,
  sum(Monitor) as Monitor,
  sum(Software) as Software 
  from User_Items_Extended
 group by Cust_Names
);

create view User_Items_Extended_Pivot_Pretty as (
 select 
  Cust_Names, 
  coalesce(Computer, 0) as Computer, 
  coalesce(Monitor, 0) as Monitor, 
  coalesce(Software, 0) as Software
from User_Items_Extended_Pivot
);
```

Comment: Use YYYY-MM-DD format for your dates, not MM-DD-YYYY.

Comment: Well that is shameful. Thank you very much. I stared at it for about an hour without seeing that.

If you'll make this an answer I'll +1 it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
case when dateChecked = '10-09-2017'
```

Use YYYY-MM-DD format for your date comparisons, not MM-DD-YYYY.