# how to pivot a table in mysql using model

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I need to pivot a table in mysql and am modeling it on [PIvoting table around date column in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129616/pivoting-table-around-date-column-in-mysql), which is almost a perfect example of what I need to do. But I'm getting no result when I run it and can't see what I'm doing wrong. 
The table I have is like this:

```
mediaID q_short_name start_time stop_time audio_file
ee  CVV Number       208        210       j.mp3
ee  Expiration Date  308        310       j.mp3
ff  CVV Number       124        127       k.mp3
ff  Expiration Date  166        169       k.mp3
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
mediaID CVVstart_T CVVstop_T Exp_start_time Exp_stop_time audio_file
ee      208      210      308            310            j.mp3
ff      124      127      166            169            k.mp3
```

so I tried this as a first step:

```
Create view my_test_extended as (select my_test.mediaID, case when 
q_short_name = 'CVV Number' then my_test.start_time end as CVVstart_T 
from my_test);
```

This is giving me Query OK, 0 rows affected. How can I adjust the query so I get the result I want?

Comment: You have curly quotes in your query, you need to use normal single quotes.

Comment: Pivoting in MySQL generally requires a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, fixed the quotes and put it in upper case and it ran without error, got Query OK, 0 rows affected.

Comment: Creating a view doesn't affect any rows, so `0 rows affected` is the expected output.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to do this in application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about a "self-join" instead of "pivot".

```
SELECT  c.mediaID,
        c.start_time AS CVVstart,
        c.end_time   AS CVVstop,
        e.start_time AS ExpStart,
        e.stop_time AS ExpStop,
        c.audio_file
    FROM  my_test AS c
    JOIN  my_test AS e  USING(mediaID)
    WHERE  c.q_short_name = 'CVV Number'
      AND  e.q_short_name = 'Expiration Date';
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Unfortunately though my table is larger than this so I'm going to have to figure out how to use self-join with a few more rows that need to become columns.