# Pivot a table in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

How to pivot a table in MySQL,

[PIvoting table around date column in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129616/pivoting-table-around-date-column-in-mysql)

I have a mysql data table as follows

```
**Student_id    Student_name    Subject Activity    Marks** 

1             Raja          Maths   null              44    
1             Raja          IT  practical     33    
1             Raja          Tamil   null              22    
1             Raja          Histry  null              54    
2             Ganga         Maths   null              33    
2             Ganga         IT  null              22    
2             Ganga         Histry  null              44    
2             Ganga         Tamil   null              89
```

So i need to pivot my table as below,

```
Student_id  Student_name    Mths    IT  Tamil   Histry  Activity

1            Raja            44 33  22  54  practical

2            Ganga           33 22  89  44  null
```

I tried to many ways by using the stackoverflow, but i couldnot able to achieve the target, need a help from the mysql expert,

Comment: consider to do data display in the application code (java)

Comment: *"I tried to many ways by using the stackoverflow, but i could not able to achieve the target, "* it is more easy to use `MAX()`/`MIN()` for pivotting as those functions allow to return anny datatype where `SUM()` only works for numeric

Comment: Yes I tried SUM() but could not, will try with max()

Comment: I don't understand your required output why are 4 marks shown and only one activity and which activity is chosen?

Comment: Have a look at this article - [Pivot Tables in MySQL](https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete the my task by using @Raymond Nijland's suggestion

[PIvoting table around date column in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129616/pivoting-table-around-date-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
(
 select Student_id, Student_name, Subject, Activity, Marks
 from #your_table
 ) src
 pivot
 (
 sum(Marks)
 for Subject in ([Maths], [IT], [Tamil], [Histry])
 ) piv;
```

Histry is written Mistakenly.. check your table data please.

Comment: This will give syntax errors on MySQL as this a SQL Server (MSSQL) query.